# How to add links for text between brackets using regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I would like to find all occurrences of text in brackets:

```
$str = 'text1 [text2] text3 [text4] text5';
```

and change them like this:

```
text1 <a href="dir/text2">text2</a> text3 <a href="dir/text4">text4</a> text5
```

I was trying to find some functions to adapt but for now regular expressions are completely incomprehensible for me.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find:

```
'~\[([^\]]+)\]~'
```

Replace:

```
'<a href="dir/$1">$1</a>'
```

Comment: Now it's replacing all ocurrances with first match. Here is my code `$reg = '"\[([^\]]+)\]"';
$str = 'text1 [text2] text3 [text4] text5';
if(preg_match($reg, $str, $url)) {

echo preg_replace($reg, '<a href="'.$url[1].'">'.$url[1].'</a>', $str);

}` Could you help me with that?